# how to update element in array using different update document for different arrayFilters

Tags: arrays, mongodb, element

suppose the document below:

```
{
     itemList:[
        {id:20,num:12}，
        {id:1,num:10}，
        {id:2,num:12}，
        {id:12,num:12}]，
     flowerId:0
}
```

how did i update the element with id =1 to make its num decrease 2 and the element with id =2 to make its num decrease 3 in a single statement?

here is my try:

```
 db.getCollection('test').update({flowerId:0},
  {$inc:{"itemList.$[elem1].num":-2},$inc:{"itemList.$[elem2].num":-3}},
  {arrayFilters:[{"elem1.id":1},{"elem2.id":2}]}
  )
```

but it just print:

```
No array filter found for identifier 'elem2' in path 'itemList.$[elem2].num'
```

how can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have only one `$inc` in update part but you can define multiple updates inside that object. This should work:

```
db.test.update(
    { flowerId:0 },
    { $inc: { "itemList.$[elem1].num": -2, "itemList.$[elem2].num": -3} },
    { arrayFilters: [ {"elem1.id":1}, {"elem2.id":2} ] }
)
```

Comment: I have done as you do , but it is as the same:                No array filter found for identifier 'elem1' in path 'itemList.$[elem1].num'

Comment: @pengji please check if document (documents) with `fioweId:0` have `id:1` it will fail otherwise. I've tested your sample doc and it worked as expected

Comment: sorry, there are other error as you say. It did success when I do this using mongoose. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: This is my first question in stackoverflow, and I am very happy to figure this question out with you help.